# Decide with Javascript which HTML Content to load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I determine via Javascript if the User is using a mobile or a Desktop Device. If he is using the Desktop Device, they should be shown the Desktop Versions of the Website, if he is using a mobile Device it should display the mobile Application. Now I'm just hiding the HTML part that is not needed with CSS but I want to get rid of this part due to loading times.

Now I want to know how I can decide by javascript which HTML Code should be loaded?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The whole idea of responsive webdesign is **one document** - that is, all devices get the *same* document.

Comment: use bootstrap, any device any brawser any size , does not matter now,

Comment: Or use any of the multitude of other responsive css frameworks

Comment: "Desktop" vs "Mobile" is a terrible distinction. What do you really care about? Viewport size? Touch Vs Pointer Vs Linear access? Internet connection speed? Internet connection cost (metered vs unmetered)? Internet connection reliability? Something else?

Comment: Maybe it was a littlebit unclear, but its about if the user enters the page with a mobile device,  the web app should be displayed (completly different layoutnot just responsive version of the desktop website) - Otherwise it should display the dekstop website which is responsive aswell. I Know how to dtermine which device he uses, but i want something like 

<div {{ if $DEVICE == mobile do load this elemen }}></div>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you're too far off. **I wouldn't have done it this way though and as others suggested I would have looked at making your HTML responsive.** With that being said, you should (simply) reverse your logic. instead of a full page where you hide elements, you should start with a blank page where you inject HTML.

https://codepen.io/chancet1982/pen/VGxZyO

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME"); // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <button>

function myFunction(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
      document.body.appendChild(btn);        
    } else {
        //Do something else..
    }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Comment: yeah so, how can i inject html files dynamicly with js ?

Answer (score 1):

I think media queries are the answer or you can use JavaScript of:

```
window.screen 

AvailableWidth = screenWidth;
AvailableHeight =screenHeight;
```

Comment: I'd say, just go with CSS. Considering Js for this is heavy and least effecient.

Comment: My Problem is not about determine if the device is mobile or not, its about to load 
 specific html only if device is mobile like 

<div {{ if $DEVICE is mobile do display this element }}></div>

Comment: Use media query and set the div  that contains that html you want to show at a certain width or height  and set to display block when that height is on  ...simple!

Answer (score -1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
< your css >
}
```

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: width of phone resolution is now greater then 600px so this case wont work, for example s9 has 2,220 x 1,080 pixels

Comment: Therefore are additional attributes...check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/